# Programming controls for sprite

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to make a snake kind of game on the iPhone. For that I plan to have a simple dot as the sprite which draws a line. The dot is controlled by two buttons on the left and the right of the screen enabling it to turn left or right. Now I really do not have any idea how to make the sprite move automatically forward and how to program the turning. It should not be exactly as in snake where it abruptly turns left or right but it should more be a smooth curve. I hope you're getting my point and I'd appreciate all kinds of thoughts! Thanks a lot!

Somewhat trying to make it like this:

http://www.bnet.im/images/screen_curve.png

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways of doing this, but one simple way would be to store the angle of the snake's trajectory (I've called it `theta`) and move it a fixed amount in every call to `Update`.

Assuming that the snake class inherits from `CCNode`:

```
-(void)Update:(ccTime)dt {
    self.position = ccp(self.position.x + cos(theta)*dt,
        self.position.y + sin(theta)*dt);
}
```

You could then update `theta` from your event handling logic by increasing it or decreasing it when the user taps to turn left or right.